# understanding base in c#

Tags: c#, oop

I'm trying to understand base constructor implementation. Consider this situation
If I have base class Sport

```
public class Sport 
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }

   public Sport() 
   {
      Console.WriteLine("Sport object is just created");
   }

   public Sport(int id, string name) 
   {           
      Console.WriteLine("Sport object with two params created");
   }
}
```

Now I have basketball class which inherhit Sport class and I want to on basketball object initialization to use second constructor with two params.

```
public class Basketball : Sport
{    
    public Basketball : base ( ???? )
    {
       ?????
    }
}
```

First I was thinking to use private fields int _Id  and string _Name and to use them in the constructor call

```
public Basketball : base ( int _Id, string _Name )
{
   Id = _Id;
   Name = _Name;
}
```

But that doesn't make sense of using inheritance, so please explain me on this example.

**Updated**
Thanks everyone, I'm using code like this and it's ok.

```
public Basketball(int id, string name) : base (id, name)
{
   Id = id;
   Name = name;
}
```

Just to make sure, On this line  `public Basketball(int id, string name) : base (id, name)` I'm declaring variables id, name, since my original are Capitalized vars, and using as params on base (id, name) to hit my base contructor.

Thank everyone., very helpful/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to pass `values` or `variables` of the `derives class` to the `base class constructor` if the base class constructor does not have any `default parameterless constructor`.

You dont need to declare anything in the base constructor call

The main purpose of base keyword is to call the `base class constructor`.

In general,if you do not declare any constructor of your own,the compiler creates a `default constructor` for you.

But if you define your own constructor having `parameter`,then the compiler does not create the `default parameterless constructor`.

So in the case where you dont have a default constructor declared in the base class and want to call a base class constructor having parameters,you have to call that base class constructor and pass the required values through `base` keyword

Do it like this

```
public Basketball() : base (1,"user")
```

**OR**

```
public Basketball(int id,string n) : base (id,n)
```

**OR**

```
public Basketball(int id,string n) : base ()
```

**OR**

```
public Basketball() : base ()
```

is similar to

```
public Basketball()//calls base class parameterless constructor by default
```

It all depends on how you want your class to **behave** when the `derived` class is instantiated

Answer (score 4):

the constructor you are asking for is the following:

```
public Basketball(int id, string name) : base(id,name) {}
```

Comment: You should explain why it works that way, since the OP does not understand the base keyword.

Answer (score 2):

Constructors aren't inherited - that's why you have to call the base constructor to re-use it.    If you don't want to do anything different other than what the base constructor does just use:

```
public Basketball( int id, string name ) : base ( id, name )
{

}
```

You example is a little misleading, however since you're not using the `id` and `name` parameters in the base constructor.  A more accurate example would be:

```
public Sport(int id, string name) 
{           
    Console.WriteLine("Sport object with two params created");

    Id = id;
    Name = name;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to either get the same parameters in Basketball's constructor:

```
public Basketball(int id, string name) : base(id, name)
```

Or somehow obtain the values in the constructor and then set them through the properties:

```
public Basketball()
{
    int id = ...;
    string name = ...;

    base.Id = id;
    base.Name = name;
}
```

Comment: @DStanley `Base` can be used to call the base class' protected and public variables and methods. However, this answer is not really relevant and does not answer the question.

Comment: @Msonic fair enough - I guess it threw me since I can't remember ever seeing overridden _properties_.

Comment: @Msonic I think it is relevant. Sometimes it's not possible to get all the arguments for a base constructor until after some code in the subclass constructor has executed.

Answer (score 0):

The keyword `base` lets you specify which parameters to pass to your base constuctor. For instance:

```
public Basketball(int _Id, string _Name) : base (_Id, _Name )
{
}
```

Will call your base constructor with 2 parameters, and:

```
public Basketball(int _Id, string _Name) : base ()
{
}
```

Will call your base constructor with no parameters. It really depends which one you want to call.