# How to pass fixed parameter to base constructor

Tags: c#, inheritance

### What

I have this coding exercise where a base class constructor should be able to define a custom property value using input parameters, but the derived class should set this property to a fixed value.

**A snippet of the exercise text:**

1. *“ Define a class `Manager`… a manager also has a monthly bonus, which should be specified at construction…”*
2. *“ Define a class `Director`. The `Director` class is supposed to be derived from the `Manager` class. A director is just a manager who has a fixed monthly bonus of 20000… When implementing the `Director` class, pay special attention to implementing the constructor correctly. **Does the class need anything else than a constructor?** “*

### Question

So how can I set this fixed value in the derived class by only having a constructor in this class? Also: the creator of the subclass object should not be able to set this property (`monthlyBonus`) at all.

### Attempt

```
//Manager inherits Employee (not interesting in this context)
public Manager(string name, int salaryPerMonth, int monthlyHours, int monthlyBonus) : base(name, salaryPerMonth)
    {
        MonthlyHours = monthlyHours;
        Bonus = monthlyBonus;
    }

public class Director : Manager
{
    public Director(string name, int salaryPerMonth, int monthlyHours, int monthlyBonus = 20000) : base(name, salaryPerMonth, monthlyHours, monthlyBonus)
    {
        //base.Bonus = 20000;
    }
}
```

- I thought about removing the input parameter `monthlyBonus` in the `Director` class in make a variable inside the constructor, but since the base class constructor gets called first thats not going to work i guess.
- I also thought about setting the input parameter value as an optional value but then the caller would be able to change this value, so this is not accepted either.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13536993/constructor-parameters-and-inheritance and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13015171/understanding-base-in-c-sharp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can directly pass values in base constructor

```
public class Director : Manager
{
    public Director(string name, int salaryPerMonth, int monthlyHours,)  
           :base(name, salaryPerMonth, monthlyHours, 20000)
    { 
    }
}
```

Comment: That was the quickest solution i have gotten yet in here. This solved it. I will mark this a solved in 9 minutes, when i'm allowed to. I actually tried something similar by putting `int monthlyBonus = 20000`, which didn't work, instead of just `20000`. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that you just need to change the constructor declaration:

```
public Director(string name, int salaryPerMonth, int monthlyHours)
    : base(name, salaryPerMonth, monthlyHours, 20000) { }
```

I.e. omit (as you already did) the `monthlyBonus` parameter, and hard-code the value when you call the base constructor using `base`.

Since this is clearly a classwork exercise, I would encourage you to ask questions focused on why it is you weren't already aware that you could do this, so that you can understand better how the `base()` constructor invocation works.

For now, I'll just point out that it's essentially the same as any other method invocation, and you can do everything with it that you can in any other method invocation. The parameters can be any expression you want; they don't need to just be a repetition of the parameters in the derived constructor.

Comment: Great answer. Thanks. I like your deep explanation of how it works, and i figure it works just like when you normally create a new object of a "normal" class without any inheritance.